# How can I see how many MySQL connections are open?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

How can I see how many connections have been opened during the current request via `mysql_connect` in PHP running on Apache?

I know that if I call `mysql_connect` function 100 times with the same parameters, it will always return the same connection link. It will not start new connection once the connection already exists.

But I just want to make sure `mysql_connect` is not starting a new one.

I am working with a legacy system which contains many `mysql_connect` function calls.

Is there any setting in Apache or is there any way I can log this number of connections in Apache or MySQL log file?

Comment: once there's a connection successfully created you could log it ofc.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I think there are a couple of ways:

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected'
```

or you can do a [`SHOW PROCESSLIST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html) and find out unique values in the `Id` column. In old PHP API `mysql`, there is [`mysql_list_processes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-processes.php) function that does the same as `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, too.

But first one should work for you. And perhaps you might like to check on other [STATUS variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html)

Answer (score 43):

There are other useful variables regarding connections and in your particular case variable [`Connections`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections) might help find out if your code is making too many connections. Just check the value before and after running code.

```
# mysql -e 'SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name LIKE "Threads_%" OR variable_name = "Connections"'

+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+
| Connections       | 22742 |
| Threads_cached    | 1     |
| Threads_connected | 87    |
| Threads_created   | 549   |
| Threads_running   | 51    |
+-------------------+-------+
```

- **Connections**

  The number of connection attempts (successful or not) to the MySQL server.
- **Threads_cached**

  The number of threads in the thread cache.
- **Threads_connected**

  The number of currently open connections.
- **Threads_created**

  The number of threads created to handle connections. If Threads_created is big, you may want to increase the thread_cache_size value. The cache miss rate can be calculated as Threads_created/Connections.
- **Threads_running**

  The number of threads that are not sleeping.

Answer (score 12):

Current connections status:

```
mysqladmin status
```

Look at `Threads:` count. More detailed information about current connections can be obtained with the commands:

```
user@host:~$ mysqladmin -uroot -ppass extended-status | grep Threads
| Threads_cached                           | 0           |
| Threads_connected                        | 3           |
| Threads_created                          | 3           |
| Threads_running                          | 1           |

user@host:~$ mysqladmin -uroot -ppass processlist
+----+------+-----------+----+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id | User | Host      | db | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+----+------+-----------+----+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 53 | root | localhost |    | Sleep   | 258  |       |                  |
| 54 | root | localhost |    | Sleep   | 253  |       |                  |
| 58 | root | localhost |    | Query   | 0    |       | show processlist |
+----+------+-----------+----+---------+------+-------+------------------+
```

**FYI** `mysqladmin -v -uroot -ppass processlist` is analog of `show full processlist`.

Commands can be shortened to any unique prefix, and called simultaneously:

```
user@host:~$ mysqladmin -v -uroot -ppass proc stat
+----+------+-----------+----+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
| Id | User | Host      | db | Command | Time | State | Info                  |
+----+------+-----------+----+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
| 53 | root | localhost |    | Sleep   | 951  |       |                       |
| 54 | root | localhost |    | Sleep   | 946  |       |                       |
| 65 | root | localhost |    | Query   | 0    |       | show full processlist |
+----+------+-----------+----+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
Uptime: 1675  Threads: 3  Questions: 171  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 235  
Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 57  Queries per second avg: 0.102
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use the MySQL command **show processlist** to get the number of connections.

Comment: Process list will show the mysql server is connected right ? Or it shows how many connections are opens ?

Comment: Yes you are right at the moment, I suppose he question was to fnd the number of connections opened at a given moment

Answer (score -1):

I dont think you can see the number of connection, but can limit the connections to the mysql server.